Test a slider on Compose Multiplatform UI
I have to test a Compose Multiplatform desktop application.
In the code I have a composable item:
Slider(modifier = Modifier.testTag("myslider"))

How can I change its value in my test?
I tried an example with swipe:
@Test
fun testSwipeHorizontal() {
    launchContent()
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("myslider")
        .performGesture {
            swipeLeft()
         }
}

which the compiler proposes to replace with performTouchInput(). What is the next I couldn't find.
Also I tried to use key press because Page Up / Page Down could change the slider's position.
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("myslider")
    .performKeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN)

But VK_PAGE_DOWN has an Int type and not a KeyEvent one.
Is there some way to test a slider in this moment?

I found the simple solution. If I know the width of my slider and its maxvalue I can write:
val width = 240
val delta = width / maxvalue
for (i in 0..< maxvalue){
    with(rule.onNodeWithTag("myslider")) {
        performMouseInput {
            click(Offset((i * delta + 1).toFloat(), 0f))
        }
    }
    rule.onNodeWithTag("mytext").assertTextEquals((i + 1).toString())
}

In such a way I can check if a mytext has been changed by my click on the slider.

By the way it worked perfectly on my PC but the build failed on deployment server so my colleague proposed another way:
onNodeWithTag("thread_count_slider").performMouseInput {
click(Offset(1f, 0f))
}
onNodeWithTag("thread_count_text").assertTextEquals("1")
    onNodeWithTag("thread_count_slider").performMouseInput {
        click(Offset(240.dp.toPx() - 1f, 0f))
    }
    onNodeWithTag("thread_count_text").assertTextEquals(maxvalue.toString())

